# Conversion between date and string

Tags: c++, string, date, time

I have a string with the following format:

YY/MM/DD,HH:MM:SS+TT (example: "16/09/18,11:34:51+04")

I'd like to be able to convert between this string and some kind of time structure back and forth. I'd also like to be able to compare the time structures to be able to find which is the most recent date.

Comment: Check and see if your system have a `strptime` function. And check out [the rest of the standard date/time functionality in the standard library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'd like to find a platform Independent solution.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you are to compare just dates. get time structure, and compare without conversion.

Comment: Perhaps the [`std::get_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time) manipulator?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude This seems to be what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What is the best way to do the reverse - convert a tm structure into string?

Comment: For output to a stream, then the [`std::put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) manipulator. Or you can use the [`std::strftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) function.